# Is there a way to assign only current property value to another property so that it won't update when the value is later changed? UWP C#

Tags: c#, image, uwp, filestream

I'm trying to make an UWP application in which you can click an add button, pick a file (an image) with file open picker and then show it in a list view item.

The problem is that I created a 'global' bitmap image as the image source which can be changed

`BitmapImage tileBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();`

So that its source is later changed to the chosen image on the click event

```
using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
{ await tileBitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream); }
```

And then the BitmapImage with its source is assigned as an Image source while creating the list view item

```
Image tileImage = new Image()
                {
                    Source = tileBitmapImage,
                    Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0),
                    Width = 400,
                    Height = 100,
                };
```

**But every time the user adds another list view item and chooses another image all the previously set images change to the just chosen image**

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

you should try to [create new image object instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37520583/940182) per call

like

```cs
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
IRandomAccessStream stream = await pic.OpenReadAsync();
bmp.SetSource(stream);

Image tileImage = new Image()
{
                    Source = bmp,
}
```

having one global tileBitmapImage variable causes all list items to show the same image (the last one was selected by user)

Comment: And what do I have to use to get this method? It shows that this method does not exist.

Comment: @TechrexStudios please find code sample adjusted for UWP platform

Comment: From what I've seen the only way to do that is with the fileStream, there is no FromFile method in UWP. Do you know any other way to make every image different?

Comment: @TechrexStudios yes there is no `FromFile` but I have updated my answer please check the source code. You should create new BitmapImage instance for each list view item

Comment: I see, but now how to 'transfer' the file stream from the open file button click event to the listViewItem-creating code?

Comment: you may create a new method in the view code behind class. It should to accept string parameter (file name) and add new list item to the collection. Just call this new method from button click event handler.

Comment: Thanks for help, I created a list of BitmapImages and the button click event handler adds a bitmap image after creating a file stream and the list view item constructor takes always the last image from the list, everything works just fine.